# Convert EOA to contract account

Tags: contract-deployment, private-key, cryptography, public-key, create2

[EIP-2026](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2026) mentions several ways of creating a new account. One way is by:

> (...) converting a non-countract account into a contract account (...)

Is this a hypothetical scenario or could this be done in practice?

I know that public keys are derived from the private key using [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc).
And contracts are created at a deterministic address using `CREATE` or [`CREATE2`](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc). Even putting these two together, I would think you would have to break cryptography to deploy a contract to an EOA. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is in your assumption that they mean convert an EOA to a contract. Yes, deploying a contract to the same address that you have a private key to would be, practically speaking, impossible. I doubt that's what is meant by the EIP though. It doesn't say anything about EOA

I think technically what that quote is referring to is accounts that have been touched but don't have a contract yet deployed to them, i.e. you calculate the address ahead of time and "touch it" - e.g. by just sending a little ETH to it. That "creates" that account, but it's not an EOA or a contract really, just an account with a balance. Then you can create a contract there since you pre-computed it in the first place, converting a non-contract account into a contract account

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.
There is no such method to convert EOA to smart contract.

EOA ( Externally Owned Account ) is normal wallets, which we all use e.g. in metamask, coinbase. It have private key.

Whereas smart contract wallet address don't have private key, it only have wallet address.